# Tracking page views and interactions for individual users in a web site

Tags: google-analytics, analytics, metrics

I'd like to track the activity per user and know how they interact with the different options and try to track all the possible clicks performed by a user.

At best would like to use a third party tool instead to create a tracking system from scratch, that definitely will boost my project development because that's a core part of my system.

I think that google analytics can perform such tasks but I can't go into that level of detail per user.

I'm using C# / ASP.NET MVC 4

thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Google Analytics (free version) does not let you view data on indivual visitor basis, only aggregated reports. The only way would be to store a unique id per visitor as a custom var and segment by that variable, which would be hugely inconvenient, would quite possibly violate Googles TOS and would still not quite work the way you want to.

You could for example install [Piwik](http://piwik.org) (if you're on PHP/Mysql) - that's an open source tracking package that, while it's pretty much useless for ad campaign management, is a halfway decent way to track how visitors move around on your site (plus, you have access to the raw data). Be aware  that Piwik doesn't scale well, you'll need a lot of hardware for a big site.

Comment: thanks for the reply, I just forgot to mention that I'm using C#/MVC a my development stack

Comment: http://piwik.org/blog/2013/02/c-sharp-tracking-and-analytics-api/ - while the main product is still php it seems that there an api client for c#.

Comment: thanks men totally appreciate your answer! but I decided to give a shot to https://mixpanel.com/ isn't for free but it got the exact functionality that I was expecting.